# Volume of the intersection of a shifted sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, spherical-coordinates

I want to find the intersection of the sphere $A:x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1$ and the sphere $B:x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

I change to spherical coordinates, with $\theta$ being the horizontal angle and $\phi$ the vertical one.

The sphere $A$ can be written as $x^2+y^2+z^2=2y$ and in spherical coordinates $A:\rho^2=2\rho \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$

$\rho$ goes from $0$ to $2\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$

Both spheres intersect at the angles $\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$

I divide the problem into two parts:

The first one is to find the volume enclosed inside the $B$ sphere. As the intersected volume is in the first and second quadrants, the angle $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$. This can be done with the next integral:

$$(1a)\ \int_{0}^\pi \int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3} \int_0^1 \; \rho^2\sin(\phi)\; d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta \;=\; \pi/3\; =\; 1.0472$$

Now where I'm having trouble is in finding the volume enclosed inside the sphere $A$.

To find the range of the $\theta$ angle, I plotted the graph $\rho(\theta,\phi)=2\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\;; \theta=0..2\;\pi,\;\phi=0..\pi/3$

[image: image 1]

Though $\phi=0..3\pi$,  the part between $\phi=2pi/3..\pi$ it's also plotted, which I don't understand it very well.

Then if the range of $\theta=0..\pi$ I get the next graph:

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

In order to find the part of volume of intersection inside the sphere $A$ I do the next integral:

$$(1b)\ 2\int_0^\pi \int_0^{\pi/3} \int_0^{2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)}\; \rho^2\sin(\phi)\;d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta\ = \ \frac{289\pi}{840}\ = 1.08086 $$

I don't understand very well this integral. I found the integration bounds mostly using the graph. And I don't understand why it is wrong.

Note: I found the volume of the intersection of the spheres $C:x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$ and $D:x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

I find it much easier to understand and grasp the idea.

The angle of intersection of both spheres was $$\frac{\pi}{3}$$
The volume of intersection enclosed inside sphere $B$ was:

(2a) $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\int_0^1\ \rho^2 \sin(\phi)\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta \;=\; \pi/3\; =\; 1.0472 $$

Equal to equation $(1a)$

For the volume of intersection inside sphere $C$ I solved  the next integral:
$$ (2b) \int_0^{2pi}\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2 \cos(\phi)}\ \rho^2 \sin(\phi)\ =\ \frac{\pi}{12}\ =\ 0.261799 $$ This outcome is right and is different than the result of (1b).

Comment: Instead of doing the usual spherical coordinates, swap the definitions of $y$ and $z$ so you only have bounds in one angular coordinate. Having both angular coordinates is not intuitive since there is no lower dimensional analogue and is nearly impossible to derive bounds graphically.

Comment: I want to solve it in spherical coordinates, if it is possible, without swapping coordinates. Swapping y and z, it is the same than solving the intersection of the sphere shifted (1-z).

Comment: If you really have your heart set on that, you should do one of the angular integrals first. I will add it to my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now reading various comments and seeing your edit, I have changed my answer accordingly to focus on mistakes in your working and what should be the correct integrals.

In fact, both $1(a)$ and $1(b)$ are incorrect.

While $1(a)$ gives you the same answer but that is just a coincidence. Limits of $\phi$ is not between $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Also on sphere $B$ in the given region, $\theta$ cannot be between $0$ and $\pi$.

At intersection of both sphere,
$\rho = 2 \sin \theta \sin \phi = 1$

$ \implies \phi = \arcsin \left(\frac {\csc\theta}{2}\right)$

Similarly below z-axis, $\phi = \pi - \arcsin \left(\frac {\csc\theta}{2}\right)$

Also at intersection $\theta$ is min when $\sin\phi$ is max, which is $1$.

So, $\sin\theta = \cfrac{1}{2} \implies \theta = \cfrac{\pi}{6}, \cfrac{5\pi}{6}$.

So the integral for $1(a)$ is,

$ \displaystyle \int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \int_{\arcsin{((\csc\theta)/2)}}^{\pi - {\arcsin{((\csc\theta)/2)}}} \int_0^1 \rho^2 \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Now coming to $1(b)$, please note that for $\frac{\pi}{6} \leq \theta \leq \frac{5\pi}{6}$, above z-axis we have, $0 \leq \phi \leq \arcsin \left(\frac {\csc\theta}{2}\right)$ and below z-axis, $\pi - \arcsin \left(\frac {\csc\theta}{2}\right) \leq \phi \leq \pi$

You should also note that for,
$0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$ and then again for $\frac{5\pi}{6} \leq \theta \leq \pi$, $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$.

So $1(b)$ is to be split into two integrals for evaluation. Using the symmetry, the integrals are,

$ \displaystyle 2 \int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \int_0^{\arcsin{((\csc\theta)/2)}} \int_0^{2\sin\theta \sin\phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi \: d\rho \: d\phi \: d\theta = \frac{(3 \sqrt3 - 5) \pi}{4} $

$ \displaystyle 2 \int_0^{\pi/6} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\sin\theta \sin\phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi \: d\rho \: d\phi \: d\theta = \left(\frac{4}{3} - \frac{ 3 \sqrt3}{4}\right) \pi $

Adding all three of them, you get the volume of the region as $\cfrac{5\pi}{12}$.

---

However if you are at ease with spherical coordinates, you could convert this into one integral by going in the order such that the outermost integral is wrt $\rho$.

For $\rho \leq 1$ in the given region, note that the bounds of $\phi$ and $\theta$ are on sphere $A$. So, $\rho = 2 \sin \theta \sin \phi \implies \phi = \arcsin \left(\cfrac{\rho \csc\theta}{2}\right)$ and similarly below z-axis, $\phi = \pi - \arcsin \left(\cfrac{\rho \csc\theta}{2}\right)$

and then, $\theta = \arcsin \left(\cfrac{\rho}{2}\right) \ $ and for $ \ x \leq 0 \ $, $\theta = \pi - \arcsin \left(\cfrac{\rho}{2}\right)$

So the integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_{\arcsin (\rho / 2)}^{\pi - \arcsin (\rho / 2)} \int_{\arcsin ((\rho \csc\theta) / 2)}^{\pi - \arcsin ((\rho \csc \theta) / 2)} \rho^2 \sin \phi \ d\phi \ d\theta \ d\rho$

Answer (score 1):

We can swap the definitions of $y$ and $z$ to obtain

$$\begin{cases}x = \rho\sin\phi\cos\theta \\ y = \rho\cos\phi \\ z = \rho\sin\phi\sin\theta\end{cases} \implies \rho = 2\cos\phi$$

then we can do the integral with $\phi$ first to do the integral in one piece

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)}\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\phi\:d\rho\:d\theta = 2\pi \int_0^1 \rho^2-\frac{\rho^3}{2}\:d\rho = \frac{5\pi}{12}$$

This gives us intuition on how to approach the original problem without swapping the $y$ and $z$ coordinates. We should approach the problem with the integration order $\phi,\theta,\rho$. First, as a function of $\phi$ the first bounds will be

$$\rho = 2\sin\phi\sin\theta \implies \phi = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sin\theta}{2}\right),\pi-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sin\theta}{2}\right)$$

(given by the $\sin(\pi-z) = \sin(z)$ reflection formula). Next, the integral projects on to the $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$ surface (the $xy$ plane since this is the widest slice possible perpendicular to the $\phi$ direction) and the exact same principle applies to find the next set of bounds

$$\rho = 2 \sin \frac{\pi}{2}\sin \theta \implies \theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right),\pi-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)$$

Now we have enough information to set up the integral

$$\int_0^1 \int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)}^{\pi-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)} \int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sin\theta}{2}\right)}^{\pi-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sin\theta}{2}\right)}\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\phi\:d\theta\:d\rho  $$

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Any chance to do it with two integrals, as in the OP?
I'd like to know if it is possible to find an integral for the part of the intersection inside sphere $A$, as I tried here$(1b)\ 2\int_0^\pi \int_0^{\pi/3} \int_0^{2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)}\; \rho^2\sin(\phi)\;d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta\ = \ \frac{289 \pi}{840}$

Comment: @robevans I updated the integral to do it without swapping $y$ and $z$. Let me know if you have any questions.